# Python list check if NoneType exists in datastructure

Tags: python

Could someone give me a tip on how to check if `None` exists in a list of floats?

```
group_temps1 = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
group_temps2 = [16.2, 18.6, 52.3, 81.6, 35.7, 88.2, 44.6, None]
group_temps3 = [16.2, 18.6, 52.3, 81.6, 35.7, 88.2, 44.6, 78.4]
```

How could I create a boolean check function?

```py
def none_checker_function(data):
    #none_checker = [temp for temp in group_temps if temp == None]
    none_checker = any(data) == None
    if none_checker:
        print("none checker found NoneTypes!")
        False
    else:
        print("none checker did Not Find NoneTypes!")
        return True
```

All return lists I have:

```
none checker did Not Find NoneTypes!
True
```

Comment: How about `None in data`? Is `data` a 2d list or a 1d list? Why are you using mixed-type lists in the first place?

Comment: Just use `None in group_temps2` etc as @ggorlen indicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `any(data)` will never be equal to `None`.

I think you meant to do something like:

```
none_checker = any([itm is None for itm in data])
```

But it's much easier than that:

```
none_checker = None in data
```

Comment: The list makes it impossible to short-circuit usefully. Even if the first item is `None`, you still need to build the full list `[True, ...]` before `any` can determine that it can return after seeing the first `True`. Use a generator expression so that `any` can return without iterating over the entire list.

Comment: But `None in data` is certainly the ideal solution in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

`any(data)` just checks if there are any truthy values in the list. You want specifically to look for `None`, so you need an expression that is true when the value is `None`.

```
if any(x is None for x in data):
    print("None checker found None!")
    return False
else:
    print("none checker did Not Find NoneTypes!")
    return True
```

Though not applicable here, you can also capture the value that makes the condition false using an assignment expression.

```
if any((bad := x) is None for x in data):
   print(f"Found the None value {bad}" in data)
```

Clearly, you can predict that `bad` is `None` if `any` returns True, but this can be useful if your test is something that could
be true for various different values.

Comment: An alternative would also be `not all(data)`, although arguably less readable.

Comment: That's less specific as well; it would reject any non-truthy `float` like `0.0` or `nan` as well.